# XmL file, need to write to the end of the "channel" element

Tags: c#, xml, rss, itunes, xelement

I'm looking to create a program to write an rss file for iTunes Podcast. I know you can buy one, but this is for experience and for a non profit organization. here is my C# code

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileLocation);
        XNamespace itunes = "http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd";


        XElement root = new XElement("item",
        (new XElement("title", textBoxPodcastTitle.Text)),
        (new XElement(itunes + "author", textBoxAuthor.Text)),
        (new XElement(itunes + "subtitle", textBoxSubtitle.Text)),
        (new XElement(itunes + "summary", textBoxSummary.Text)),
        (new XElement("enclosuer",
                    new XAttribute("url", "\"http://www.jubileespanish.org/Podcast/\"" + textBoxFileName.Text + "\"" + " length=\"" + o_currentMp3File.Length.ToString() + "\" type=\"audio/mpeg\""))),
        (new XElement("guid", "http://www.jubileespanish.org/Podcast/" + textBoxFileName.Text)),
        (new XElement("pubDate", o_selectedMP3.currentDate())),
        (new XElement(itunes + "duration", o_selectedMP3.MP3Duration(openFileDialogFileName.FileName.ToString()))),
        (new XElement("keywords", textBoxKeywords.Text)));

        doc.Element("channel").Add(root);
        doc.Save(fileLocation);
```

everything works fine except when I am writing the root XElement I made. It cannot write it because in the iTunes channel element there are other elements besides the "item" elements.(The rest of the podcast info). How can I append it inside the channel element but right before the closing tag. Here is how the xml file looks like. Thanks, I'm new be gentle...

```
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0">
<channel>
     <title>Non Profit company</title>
     <itunes:keywords>keywords</itunes:keywords>
     <itunes:image href="http://www.podcast.org/Podcast/podcastlogo.png" />
     <itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>
     <itunes:block>no</itunes:block>


<item>
  <title>Red, Whine, &amp; Blue</title>
  <itunes:author>Various</itunes:author>
  <itunes:subtitle>Red + Blue != Purple</itunes:subtitle>
  <itunes:summary>This week we talk about surviving in a Red state if you are a Blue person. Or vice versa.</itunes:summary>
  <itunes:image href="http://example.com/podcasts/everything/AllAboutEverything/Episode3.jpg" />
  <enclosure url="http://example.com/podcasts/everything/AllAboutEverythingEpisode1.mp3" length="4989537" type="audio/mpeg" />
  <guid>http://example.com/podcasts/archive/aae20050601.mp3</guid>
  <pubDate>Wed, 1 Jun 2005 19:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
  <itunes:duration>3:59</itunes:duration>
  <itunes:keywords>politics, red, blue, state</itunes:keywords>
</item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

I would like to append right before the

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
        doc.Root.Element("channel").Add(root);
```

Element retrieved by accessing the `Root` property is `rss` and the `Add` method will add the element to the end of the element's content by default.

Other possible ways to do this would be:

```
        doc.Element("rss").Element("channel").Add(root);
```

or:

```
        var el = doc.Descendants("channel").FirstOrDefault();
        if (el != null)
            el.Add(root);
```

But the first one (using `Root` property) would be the cleanest.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I used your second example. it worked perfectly.